# Render Popup from Background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I've developed a chrome extension. Its a chat app.

I developed whole application as a popup, later on I realised that popups destroy completely when out-of-focus.
As a chat app, I want the popup to stay in background to deliver notifications but there seems no way to keep a popup in background(please correct if I am wrong).

My app is written mostly in angularJS with a server API.

I am thinking of first rendering my app as a background page and then whenever popup is clicked It will get the DOM from background page.

**What I tried:**

I shifted all popup's html to background page and in the popup's markup I tried loading background page's markup by:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

but that's not working as it just displays the markup rendered by Angular.

Now I am thinking if there is some way I can use iframes to show backgroundPage?

Please help me in accomplishing this.

Comment: Try injecting an iframe into the inspected page, the source being your `chrome-extension://<id>/background.html`. Inspected page might not play well with CORS though.

Comment: A relative URL is just fine since the *origins* are same (so CORS is not a problem): `<iframe src="background.html"></iframe>`

Comment: You could just open a window and use that as a long term popup: `chrome.windows.create({type:'panel',url:'someFileInYourExtension.html},winId=>{myPanelWinId=inId});`. Given that such panels can and will go into the background, and are not associated with any particular browser window, it sound more along the lines of what you desire.

Comment: @Makyen your idea seems good, please ellaborate

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like to see as an elaboration. My comment suggests that this question, as stated, is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). In other words, it is focusing on the way that you are currently thinking of resolving your problem (rendering from HTML in the background page) rather than asking about methods of solving your larger problem (how to present your UI to the user). The approach I suggested doesn't really have much of anything to do with this question, as explicitly stated. Thus, I'm not sure what elaboration would be appropriate.

Comment: @Makyen I just wan't to know how to use panels, the code you gave creates a panel that destroys itself on closing but you said panels can go in background, how?

Comment: @Richard, It sounds like we are using "background" to mean different things. Your description implies that by "background" you mean "keep running when the view to the page is destroyed".  When I said "background" I meant that it can loose focus and still be existent; that the window can still exist even if it is minimized, or otherwise not currently visible to the user (i.e. underneath the currently visible window). I did not mean to imply that it continued to exist after it is destroyed/closed.